# Implementing a hierarchical system in django using django treebeard

Tags: django, django-models, hierarchical-data, materialized-path-pattern, django-treebeard

I am trying to implement a web based organisational church system which has a hierarchy as shown in the diagram.

I want to implement the system using django treebeard materialized path.

I want each node on the tree to be an instance of a Church where a single church in the tree can manage its content also the Admin and the users can be able to login to the Church they belong to.

I also need the parent node to be able to access the some data of the child nodes.

Is this possible? If you have any idea or leads, please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: here is a diagram of the tree]

Comment: Yes that should be suitable. `django-cms` uses it to nest it's pages into a tree.

Comment: Hi markwalker_  thanks for your response, is there any lead or somewhere you can refer me to pertaining the question, thank you.

Comment: I've never built anything with treebeard so I'd only be googling like you could. I'd personally start with their docs unless you can see anything like a good tutorial or article